# Issue with ACF repeater accordeon loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I've been trying to integrade accordeon blocs in an ACF loop as so :

```
<?php elseif ( get_row_layout() == 'accordeon' ) : ?>
    <?php if ( have_rows( 'cases' ) ) : ?>
        <div class="accordeon-bloc clear">
            <?php while ( have_rows( 'cases' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                <div class="tab">
                    <input id="tab" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
                    <label for="tab"><?php the_sub_field( 'titre_du_bloc' ); ?></label>
                    <div class="tab-title"><?php the_sub_field( 'label' ); ?></div>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <p><?php the_sub_field( 'descriptif' ); ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php // no rows found ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

An here is the CSS :

```
input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.tab-content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .35s;
}

/* :checked */
.tab input:checked ~ .tab-content {max-height: 10em;}
```

So here is my issue : when I add more than one accordeon bloc, I have several tab divs, but when I click on the "+" to reveal the tab-content bloc, it always show the first one's content, as they obviously all have the same class.

I hadn't thought of that issue before building the loop and I can't find out how to solve this. I have zero knowledge in javascript but maybe there's a solution here ? Or something with CSS and selecting the nth / nth + 1 element ?

Thanks in advance for you help !

EDIT :
I found a solution by adding an ID field in ADF and by modifing the loop as so :

```
<div class="tab">
    <input id="<?php the_sub_field( 'identifiant' ); ?>" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
    <label for="<?php the_sub_field( 'identifiant' ); ?>"><?php the_sub_field( 'icone' ); ?><?php the_sub_field( 'titre_du_bloc' ); ?></label>
    <div class="tab-title"><?php the_sub_field( 'label' ); ?></div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <p><?php the_sub_field( 'descriptif' ); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But maybe there's a better solution that doesn't require manual input !

Comment: Can you add the js you're currently using to reveal the content?

Comment: There is no JS as the accordeon is pure CSS

Comment: You should be able to achieve it without using a specific id for input, check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the container (`<div class="tab">` in this case) was missing the `position: relative` attribute and the various `input` ended up one on top of another, because of the `position: absolute` attribute.

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8v0j3pq/1/) with the following changes:

```
.tab { position: relative; }

.tab input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}
```